# "w: Some runtime JAR files in the classpath have an incompatible version. Consider removing them from the classpath " seeing in react native

Tags: java, android, react-native

/Users/apple/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.5.20/3d79dbd48bf605f4aac1e7028981a1953e245cbb/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.5.20.jar (version 1.5)
w: Some runtime JAR files in the classpath have an incompatible version. Consider removing them from the classpath

> Task :app:packageRelease FAILED
> w: Detected multiple Kotlin daemon sessions at build/kotlin/sessions

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact$IncrementalSplitterRunnable
> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError (no error message)